# IntelliJ auto format breaks Angular Sass Files

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, sass, webstorm

I have an Angular project using `.sass` stylesheets using IntelliJ IDE.

When using `::ng-deep`, IntelliJ flags the double colon as an error and on reformat, splits the colons.  This is highly inconvenient, as I have autoformat configured as part of my commit pipeline.

Is there a way to either:

1. Update the style rules to recognize the double colon as valid?

OR

2. Turn off autoformat on commit only for Sass files?

Example:

```
.icon-container
  width: 100%
  font-size: xxx-large
  text-align: center

  :host ::ng-deep
    text-align: center
```

is incorrectly formatted to:

```
.icon-container
  width: 100%
  font-size: xxx-large
  text-align: center

  :host: :ng-deep
    text-align: center
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow [WEB-42952](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42952) and linked ticket for updates.

For now, I can only suggest adding your `.sass` files to **Do not format:** list in **Settings | Editor | Code Style, Formatter**

Comment: Followed - thanks for the pointer on the formatter settings.